# how to seek a specific line to append data or append data to last line in c++

Tags: c++, file, c++11, ofstream

In my iteration to write data to file, I would like write data to different lines.

Looks like:

0.2 0.3

1 2

0.4 0.5 `cursor should be here`

Now I will append data:

0.6

3

0.6

so I need to back the first line append `0.6` and then move next to append `3` and then `0.6`.

How to do that using c++? I open file using ofstream as append mode and I am now using c++ with stl c++11. `seekp` seems only move a character step not for a line step. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Doing it in files is not something I recommend, as each time you write in it you will be *replacing* the current contents. It might be easier to read the full file into memory, and then move the memory around. Or modify while reading. Or modify while (over) writing.

Answer (score 2):

Append mode only works for adding data to the very end of the file, not to places in the middle like you want.

For this, you'll pretty much need to copy the file line by line, and add the data as appropriate, something on this general order:

```
std::vector<double> additions { 0.6, 3, 0.6 };

std::string line;

for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    std::getline(infile, line);
    outfile << line;
    outfile << " " << additions[i];
}
```

Comment: `outfile << line` will not override those lines below current line in append mode?

Comment: @NickDong: The intent here is reading from the existing file, and writing the data to a new (previously empty) file.